# Не могу выполнить команду prisma deploy

Tags: graphql

[image: что пишет консоль]

Существоующий проект, после переустановки винды не могу выполнить команду prisma deploy не видит prisma, перед попыткой prisma глобально установил

Answer (score 0):

сработало yarn prisma deploy, может я что путаю но до переутстановки винды работало prisma deploy